# pandas looking at next row and swapping values

Tags: python, pandas

If i see a A&T consecutively,

1. I will set found=True for A. set remove=True for T.
2. Set value of T as A (copy A's value to T)
3. Set T found=True

If I see G&C consecutively,

1. I will set found=True for G. set remove=True for C
2. Swap G & C Values

---

Original dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['A','3'],['T','4'],
                 ['A','3'],['A','4'],
                 ['G','3'],['C','4'],
                 ['T','1']
                 ],
                columns=['Flag','Value'])
df['found']=False
df['remove']=False


print df

  Flag Value  found remove
0    A     3  False  False
1    T     4  False  False
2    A     3  False  False
3    A     4  False  False
4    G     3  False  False
5    C     4  False  False
6    T     1  False  False
```

Desired Dataframe

```
  Flag Value  found remove
0    A     3   True  False
1    T     3  False   True
2    A     3  False  False
3    A     4  False  False
4    G     4   True  False
5    C     3  False   True
6    T     1  False  False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create some temporary columns to track the lagged flags and values and next flags.  Then you can compare directly:

```
df['prior_flag'] = df.Flag.shift()
df['next_flag'] = df.Flag.shift(-1)
df['prior_value'] = df.Value.shift()

# Check for 'A' followed by 'T'
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'A') & (df.next_flag == 'T'), 'found'] = True
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'T') & (df.prior_flag == 'A'), 'remove'] = True
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'T') & (df.prior_flag == 'A'), 'Value'] = \
    df.loc[(df.Flag == 'T') & (df.prior_flag == 'A'), 'prior_value']

# Check for 'G' followed by 'C'
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'G') & (df.next_flag == 'C'), 'found'] = True
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'C') & (df.prior_flag == 'G'), 'remove'] = True
temp = df.loc[(df.Flag == 'G') & (df.next_flag == 'C'), 'Value'].values
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'G') & (df.next_flag == 'C'), 'Value'] = \
    df.loc[(df.Flag == 'C') & (df.prior_flag == 'G'), 'Value'].values
df.loc[(df.Flag == 'C') & (df.prior_flag == 'G'), 'Value'] = temp
df.drop(['next_flag', 'prior_flag', 'prior_value'], axis=1, inplace=True)

>>> df
  Flag Value  found remove
0    A     3   True  False
1    T     3  False   True
2    A     3  False  False
3    A     4  False  False
4    G     4   True  False
5    C     3  False   True
6    T     1  False  False
```

Because you want to swap values when G is followed by C, I created a temporary variable `temp` to store the intermediate copy value.

All temporary columns are then dropped at the end.

To view the remaining rows that have not been removed:

```
>>> df[~df.remove]
  Flag Value  found remove
0    A     3   True  False
2    A     3  False  False
3    A     4  False  False
4    G     4   True  False
6    T     1  False  False
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  How can I evaluate this in pairs? Since, I evaluated 0,1 row, I want to skip evaluating 1,2 instead I want to evaluate 2,3.

Comment: @user3589054 See revised response to view only those names that have not been removed.  Per your question in your comment, it is difficult to efficiently remove/stop evaluating row 1 and move directly to row 2.  One could use iterrows to sequentially evaluate each row in the data frame, but this is quite slow because a new Series much be created for each one. Depending on what you mean by 'evaluate', you could have any expensive calculation based on whether or not the 'remove' flag has been set.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
To solve it, i was thinking of adding another criteria such as  Flag=A&NextFlag=T&Remove=False. Once remove is set to true (second line) it should not evaluate but I am not sure if does this operation in parallel or sequentially  if it does then it won't work. i am afraid it will do it parallel and independently. I am curios how the iterrows solution would look like