# Python: using pandas.pivot_table to flatten activity logs and display time spent doing activities

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pivot-table

I'm looking at using python and pandas to flatten our VLE (Blackboard inc.) activity table. I'm trying to sum the total time spent per day on accessing courses as opposed to doing other non course activity in the activity logs/table.

I've created some fake data and code below (python) to simulate the question and where I'm struggling. It's the flattened_v2 part I'm struggling with as that's close to my actual case.

The log data typically looks like this and I've created it below in the code example: (activity dataframe in the code below)

```
         DAY    event somethingelse  timespent             logtime
0 2013-01-02     null           foo   0.274139 2013-01-02 00:00:00
0 2013-01-02  course1           foo   1.791061 2013-01-02 01:00:00
1 2013-01-02  course1           foo   0.824152 2013-01-02 02:00:00
2 2013-01-02  course1           foo   1.626477 2013-01-02 03:00:00
```

I've got a field called logtime in the real data. This is an actual datetime rather than a time spent field( also included in my fake data as I was experimenting).

How do I record total time spent (using logtime) on event = course (many courses)?

Each record contains logtime which shows datetime to access page
Next record logtime shows the datetime accessing new page and therefore leaving old page (close enough). How can I get the total time where event is not null. If I just use the max/min values then this leads to an overestimate as the gaps in course access (where event = null) are also included. I've simplified the data so that each record increments by 1 hour which isn't the real case.

Thanks for any tips
Jason

The code is:

```
# dataframe example
# How do I record total time spent on event = course (many courses)?
# Each record contains logtime which shows datetime to access page
# Next record logtime shows the datetime accessing new page and
# therefore leaving old page (close enough)
# 
#

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


# Creating fake data with string null and course1, course2
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DAY' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
    'timespent' : abs(np.random.randn(5)),
    'event' : "course1",
    'somethingelse' : 'foo' })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DAY' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
    'timespent' : abs(np.random.randn(5)),
    'event' : "course2",
    'somethingelse' : 'foo' })

dfN =pd.DataFrame({
    'DAY' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
    'timespent' : abs(np.random.randn(1)),
    'event' : "null",
    'somethingelse' : 'foo' })


dfLog = [dfN, df,df2,dfN,dfN,dfN,df2,dfN,dfN,df,dfN,df2,dfN,df,df2,dfN, ]
activity = pd.concat(dfLog)
# add time column
times = pd.date_range('20130102', periods=activity.shape[0], freq='H')
activity['logtime'] = times

# activity contains a DAY field (probably not required)
# timespent -this is fake time spent on each event. This is
# not in my real data but I started this way when faking data
# event -either a course or null (not a course)
# somethingelse -just there to indicate other data. 
#

print activity # This is quite close to real data.

# Fake activity date created above to demo question.

# *********************************************
# Actual code to extract time spent on courses
# *********************************************

# Lambda function to aggregate data -max and min

# Where time diff each minutes.
def agg_timespent(a, b):
    c = abs(b-a)
    return c

# Where the time difference is not explicit but is 
# record of time recorded when accessing page (course event)
def agg_logtime(a, b):
    # In real data b and a are strings
    # b = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    c = abs(b-a).seconds
    return c    



# Remove 'null' data as that's not of interest here. 
# null means non course activity e.g. checking email
# or timetable -non course stuff.
activity= activity[(activity.event != 'null') ]

print activity  # This shows *just* course activity info

# pivot by Day (only 1 day in fake data but 1 year in real data)
# Don't need DAY field but helped me fake-up data
flattened_v1 = activity.pivot_table(index=['DAY'], values=["timespent"],aggfunc=[min, max],fill_value=0)
flattened_v1['time_diff'] = flattened_v1.apply(lambda row: agg_timespent(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)


# How to achieve this?
# Where NULL has been removed I think this is wrong as NULL records could
# indicate several hours gap between course accesses but as
# I'm using MAX and MIN then I'm ignoring the periods of null
# This is overestimating time on courses
# I need to subtract/remove/ignore?? the hours spent on null times

flattened_v2 = activity.pivot_table(index=['DAY'], values=["logtime"],aggfunc=[min, max],fill_value=0)
flattened_v2['time_diff'] = flattened_v2.apply(lambda row: agg_logtime(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)

print
print '*****Wrong!**********'
print 'This is not what I have but just showing how I thought it might work.'
print flattened_v1
print
print '******Not sure how to do this*********'
print 'This is wrong as nulls/gaps are also included too'
print flattened_v2
```

Comment: I thought by creating the demo code it might help me solve it. I'm thinking that creating a new field for each row which includes the logtime for the next record might help? Then I could get the difference between logtimes on each row/record, *then* filter out null values *then* sum the times. The last row/record would just be the row/record logtime. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi
[dataframe.shift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901947/pandas-looking-at-next-row-and-swapping-values) might be what I'm looking for.
Jas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right (in your comment): you'll need `dataframe.shift`.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to record the time *elapsed* since the last timestamp, so timestamps signify the beginning of an activity, and when the last activity was `null` we should not record any elapsed time. Assuming that's all correct, use `shift` to add a column for time differences:

```
activity['timelog_diff'] = activity['logtime'] - activity['logtime'].shift()
```

Now the first row will show the special "not a time" value `NaT`, but that's fine as we can't calculate elapsed time there. Next we can fill in some more `NaT` values for any elapsed time where a `null` event has just occurred:

```
mask = activity.event == 'null'
activity.loc[mask.shift(1).fillna(False), 'timelog_diff'] = pd.NaT
```

When we want to find out how much time was spent on `course1`, we have to shift again, because indexing for the `course1` rows will produce rows where `course1` is beginning. We need those where `course1` is finishing/has finished:

```
activity[(activity.event == 'course1').shift().fillna(False)]['timelog_diff'].sum()
```

That returns 15 hours for `course1` and 20 for `course2` in your example.

Comment: That's great thank you. And the extra course shift too.